# Objective C - Category No Visible selector @removeWhiteSpaceStringWithString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, objective-c-category

so im trying to add new method for testing using Category from `NSString`, but some how i must declared like this with following step:

1. Create Category from `NSString` with name `StringExtension` so it will be `NSString+StringExtension`, after that i declared my own methos that return type is `String`
2. so after i define in `NSString+StringExtension` `@interface` and `@implementation`, i tried in my viewController to called it, but first i import the class `NSString+StringExtension`
3. after that i do like this

   ```objectivec
   NSString *testString = @"as d a s d";
   NSLog(@"===== %@", [testString removeWhiteSpaceStringWithString:testString]);
   ```
4. and it says

   > No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'removeWhiteSpaceStringWithString:'

the question is, why it cannot use like that? i already search and see tutorial doing like that and its possible, but why i'm not able to do that?

so i found this way, but i don't know is this the correct code to use?

```objectivec
NSLog(@"===== %@", [[testString class] removeWhiteSpaceStringWithString:testString]);
```

anyone have the same case like i am?

Comment: Can you post the code in your NSString+StringExtension.h file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon what you have shared with us, it would appear that you defined a class method (with `+`). It should be an instance method (with `-`) and then you don’t need the parameter, either. You can simply reference `self`.

For example:

```objectivec
//  NSString+Whitespace.h

@import Foundation;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface NSString (Whitespace)

- (NSString *)stringByRemovingWhitespace;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

And

```objectivec
//  NSString+Whitespace.m

#import "NSString+Whitespace.h"

@implementation NSString (Whitespace)

- (NSString *)stringByRemovingWhitespace {
    return [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\s+"
                                           withString:@""
                                              options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)];
}

@end
```

Then you can do:

```objectivec
NSString *testString = @"as d a s d";
NSLog(@"===== %@", [testString stringByRemovingWhitespace]);  // ===== asdasd
```

Obviously, do whatever you want in your implementation, but it illustrates the idea, that you want an instance method and you do not need to pass the string again as a parameter.

Comment: hi @rob, nice ! i've no idea why it i declaring with (+), and it solved my problem! thanks a lot for the solution and explanation. was so confuse before. bless you!

Comment: Yeah, extensions can include both class and instance methods. Perhaps the example you started from was a class method. But in this case, instance method makes more sense. Good luck and happy coding